# Why .java file shows as .class file in src folder in github repository?

Tags: java, git, github

I am committing a Java project to a GitHub repository from IntelliJ IDEA. I pushed my project to the Git repo, but when I viewed the src folder, all .java files shows up as .class files. What should I do?

These are the files in the src folder:

[image: files in folder]

Also, I cannot view the code itself in Github when I view a specific file.

EDIT: Sorry I was looking another directory not **src** folder. Anyways thanks for answers)

[image: here is the screenshot of it]

Comment: You pushed the wrong files. Not sure why. Class files should not be in the src folder.

Comment: .Class files are the .Java files after you have compiled your project (it is a process done by the JVM). Have you done something before pushing your project into your Git repo?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can ignore the .class files folder when using git to push your process

Comment: You should explain how to do this with .gitignore

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-ask).